# CONNECTING INTERNET AND LAN

Tags: networking

I have 20 PCs in a lan CONNECTED TO 24 PORT UNMANAGED D-LINK SWITCH. Each of the machines have specific ip like 192.168.0.1....20, subnet mask 255.255.255.0.  Each machines can be accessed by their names.
I have a PC where i have internet connected to ethrnet via a hub.(ip: 10.188.10.xxx; subnet 255.255.240.0)  From this hub i need to connect to the above said LAN.  I can change the IP of LAN PCs for connecting to internet.
I tried connecting one port of HUB to one port of SWITCH in the LAN.  I could not connect to PCs in the LAN (access within themselves could not be done)

Comment: Do you want only access to LAN from PC connected to the hub?

Answer (score 1):

Connect your `switch` to your `hub` using a `Ethernet` cable. Add a secondary IP address on your PC which is directly connected to the `hub` from IP range `192.168.0.0/24` . Now every PCs in your LAN is accessible from the PC.